# "fallbackLoader option has been deprecated - replace with "fallback""

Tags: webpack, angular-cli

After upgrading my Angular CLI 1.0.0-beta.26 project to Angular CLI 1.0.0-beta.30, I get the following two warning:

```
fallbackLoader option has been deprecated - replace with "fallback"
loader option has been deprecated - replace with "use"
```

as part of the build.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An [Angular CLI PR has been committed](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/73d562868ec1427a3619704a2dc7d60f3159b762) to address these warnings, so [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/4435) should be addressed in `1.0.0-beta.31` and up.

To address these warnings now, you can make the following changes to the webpack configuration:

```
loader:          -->  use:
fallbackLoader:  -->  fallback:
```

Note: if you re-install `node_modules` you'll need to re-do these changes.

**Details**

For **`Angular CLI 1.0.0-beta.30`**, in `node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/styles.js` find the global style path section and change it from:

```
    loader: [
      ("css-loader?" + JSON.stringify({ sourceMap: cssSourceMap })),
    ].concat(commonLoaders, loaders),

    fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',

    publicPath: ''
```

to:

```
    use: [
      ("css-loader?" + JSON.stringify({ sourceMap: cssSourceMap })),
    ].concat(commonLoaders, loaders),

    fallback: 'style-loader',

    publicPath: ''
```

For **`Angular CLI 1.0.0-beta.26`**, in `./node_modules/angular-cli/models/webpack-build-styles.js` find the global style path section and change it from:

```
    loader: ['css-loader'].concat(commonLoaders, loaders),

    fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',

    publicPath: ''
```

to:

```
    use: ['css-loader'].concat(commonLoaders, loaders),

    fallback: 'style-loader',

    publicPath: ''
```

Comment: make sure to use @angular/cli not angular-cli, they stopped updating the latter.

Comment: I don't think this is still valid, check this error: `Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[1] has an unknown property 'fallback'.`

Comment: Could be, @Lofus -- consider opening a new issue with all the details so more up-to-date information can be shared...

Comment: @Jan Nielsen, Further debugging and I found out that the fallback property is only a member of `configuration.plugins` and not `configuration.module.rules`. Are you still able to run your fallback next to the use statement like the posted answer?

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using Angular CLI 1.0.0-beta.26, the correct path to identify and fix this problem is:

`node_modules/angular-cli/models/webpack-configs/styles.js`

You should see this:

```
// load global css as css files
if (globalStylePaths.length > 0) {
    rules.push.apply(rules, baseRules.map(function (_a) {
        var test = _a.test, loaders = _a.loaders;
        return ({
            include: globalStylePaths, test: test, loaders: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                loader: [
                    // css-loader doesn't support webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin properly,
                    // so we need to add options in its query
                    ("css-loader?" + JSON.stringify({ sourceMap: cssSourceMap }))
                ].concat(commonLoaders, loaders),
                fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
                // publicPath needed as a workaround https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4035
                publicPath: ''
            })
        });
    }));
}
```

- Change the **loader** to `use`, and the **fallbackLoader** to `fallback`
- Note also that this has been fixed in the latest release.

Comment: It appears the path you're pointing to is pre-.30 -- same path as I note in the second section in **Details**...

Comment: Sure, there is no difference and nothing new, but just to help people be sure of what to see when they get to the particular `style.js` file.

Comment: I have amended it accordingly. Thanks